Angular Unit Testing. How to mock HttpResponse (JasminKarma)
Currently trying to write unit test for frontend. but I'm having issues with how the expected type. I keep getting expected 'Expected<HttpResponse>' on my provided mock response. I have my mock response set up like
        const resp = {
            body: null,
            status: 200,
            statusText: 'Success',
            type: HttpEventType.Response,
            clone: '',
            headers: '',
            url: '',
            ok: ''
        };

thanks!

The test cases sometimes throw error for full typing not being present, but we cannot waste time, providing the full typing for all test cases, the solution is to use any to override these typing errors and just test the values returned.
    const resp = {
        body: null,
        status: 200,
        statusText: 'Success',
        type: HttpEventType.Response,
        clone: '',
        headers: '',
        url: '',
        ok: ''
    } as any;

This as any will bypass the typescript error.
